# i18next How to detect language preference stored in database?

Tags: graphql, react-i18next

I'm developing a react-native app with `react-i18next`, and I want to implement 2 things below.

1. Detect user's language preference stored in backend and use it.
2. Detect device's language and use it when there is no language preference data in backend.

I've already implemented **2.** like below, but not **1.**.
How can I do it?
I'm using `Prisma`, `Graphql`

```
import i18n from 'i18next';
import { NativeModules, Platform } from 'react-native';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';
let locale;
if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
  locale = NativeModules.SettingsManager.settings.AppleLocale;
} else {
  locale = NativeModules.I18nManager.localeIdentifier;
}
if (!locale) {
  locale = 'en';
}

let language = 'en';
if (locale === 'ja_JP') {
  language = 'ja';
} else if (locale.includes('zh')) {
  language = 'cn';
} else {
  language = 'en';
}

i18n
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    resources,
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    lng: language,
    keySeparator: true,

    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false,
    },
  });
```